# Reading a json file in key value pair in the same order that's given in input

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-3.0

I am writing a PowerShell Script, which will read a json file having different sections, like job1, job2 and so on.. Now my objective is to read each section separately and to loop through it as a key value pair. I also need to maintain the order of the input file, because the jobs are scheduled in sequence. and these jobs run taking the values from the json file as input.

I tried using Powershell version 5.1, in which I created PSCustomObject but the order is getting sorted alphabetically, which I DON'T want.

---

Json File :

```
{ "Job1": [
        {
    "Ram"                                   : "India",
    "Anthony"                               : "London",
    "Elena"                                 : "Zurich"
    }],

    "Job2": [
            { 
    "Build"                                : "fail",
    "Anthony"                              : "right",
    "Sam"                                  : "left"

    }]}
```

---

```
$json = Get-Content -Path C:\PowershellScripts\config_File.json | 
ConvertFrom-Json

$obj = $json.Job1

$json.Job1 | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | ForEach-Object {

$key = $_.Name
$values  = [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{Key = $key; Value = $obj."$key"}
$values
}
```

I am expecting to loop through each section separately and in the same order that's provided in the json file. For example looping through Job1 section and to fetch only the Values in the same order that's in the json file.

Comment: Would you consider using a classic for loop instead? `for($i=0;$i-lt $json.Job1.count;$i++){..your stuff here..}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will guarantee that this is not the best way to do this, but it works.

```
$json = Get-Content -Path C:\PowershellScripts\config_File.json | 
    ConvertFrom-Json
$out = ($json.Job1 | Format-List | Out-String).Trim() -replace "\s+(?=:)|(?<=:)\s+"
$out -split "\r?\n" | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{Key = $_.Split(":")[0]; Value = $_.Split(":")[1]}
}
```

**Explanation:**

The JSON object is first output using `Format-List` to produce the `Property : Value` format, which is piped to `Out-String` to make that output a single string. `Trim()` is used to remove surrounding white space.

The `-replace` removes all white space before and after `:` characters.

The `-split \r?\n` splits the single string into an array of lines. Each of those lines is then split by the `:` character (`.Split(":")`). The `[0]` index selects the string on the left side of the `:`. The `[1]` selects the string on the right side of the `:`.

Comment: it is working fine, but for json file having larger names, its not working. For example some of the content of my json file is like  : Serviceability Deployment Package"            : "Customer_DeployWestpacServiceabilityDeploymentPackage" . It is not working for this.

Comment: Right. Actually I have approximately, 20 values for each Job. There was new line entered in between the values which created the problem, after the removal of new line it is working fine. Thanks mate..

Comment: Can you please explain the regex that you have used here ? It's behaving very weird. Sometimes its working fine, but sometimes its splitting the last few letters of the value.

Comment: I added explanation in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can you change the json schema?
I would probably make changes to the json schema before i tried to parse this (if possible of course).
Like this (changed only Job1):

```
$json = @"
{ "Job1": [
        {
            "Name": "Ram",
            "Location" : "India"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Anthony",
            "Location": "London"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Elena" ,
            "Location": "Zurich"
        }
    ],

    "Job2": [
            { 
    "Build"                                : "fail",
    "Anthony"                              : "right",
    "Sam"                                  : "left"

    }]}
"@ | convertfrom-json


foreach ($obj in $json.Job1) {

    $key = $obj.Name
    $values = [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{Key = $key; Value = $obj."$key" }
    $values
}
```

Comment: Your logic looks good and is working as expected, but the size/no. of rows have grown huge. Let's see what others have to say.